# Como printar linhas no txt a partir de uma variável e manipular esses dados - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por favor, amigos, estou trabalhando em um script em python que le um arquivo txt e a partir de dois valores que existe em algumas linhas, ele printa em um novo arquivo txt. Alem disso, os resultados precisam ficar juntos, ou seja, caso essas duas variáveis esteja 6 linhas distintas, pra mim não faz sentido o resultado.

```
proxy_set_header X-Samesite-Support "$xSamesiteSupport";\
proxy_pass
\
map $http_cookie $interceptError \{\
proxy_pass
    ~*(force_error=1) false;\
    default  true;\
\}\
\
server \{\
  listen 8080;\
  listen 8443 ssl;\
  proxy_connect_timeout 1000ms;\
  server_name ~^sample.(exemplo|nginx)\\..*$;\
\
  location /exemplo/exemplo/sample \{\
    proxy_pass http://exemplo;\
  \}\
\
  location /nginx/monitoring/sample \{\
    return 200;\
  \}\
\
\
\}\
\
#  --- exemplo -----\
\
server \{\
    listen 8080;\
    listen 8443 ssl;\
        server_name exemplo.com;\
\
\
    location / \{\
      client_max_body_size 2000m;\
        proxy_pass http://exemplo.com;  \
    \}\
\
\}\
\
```

Neste exemplo acima, precisaria printar apenas os dois campos server_name e proxy_pass um abaixo do outro em um txt ou em um xls, um ao lado do outro.

ficaria dessa forma, retirando o lixo de campos que nao tem juntos:

```
-------------------------------------------
server_name ~^sample.(exemplo|nginx)\\..*$;\
        proxy_pass http://exemplo;\
-------------------------------------------
            server_name exemplo.com;\
            proxy_pass http://exemplo.com;  \
-------------------------------------------
```

O que eu consegui desenvolver ate agora:
Consigo printar apenas uma das infos, não esta printando as duas, nem de forma distinta:

```
in_file = "/Users/usuario1/Desktop/Consult/APIsfront.txt"
out_file = "/Users/usuario1/Desktop/results.txt"

search_for = "server_name"
search_for2 = "proxy_pass"

line_num = 0
line_num2 = 0
lines_found = 0

with open(out_file, 'w') as out_f:
    
    with open(in_file, "r") as in_f:

        for line in in_f:
            line_num += 1

            if search_for in line:
                lines_found += 1

        with open(in_file, "r") as in_f2:
            for line in in_f2:
                line_num2 +=1

                if search_for2 in line:
                    lines_found +=1

                    print("Found '{}' and {} in line {}... ".format(search_for, search_for2, line_num))

                    out_f.write(line)



        print("Found {} lines...".format(lines_found))
```

Um colega me sugeriu usar o counter e dando um append no arquivo fechado, mas não entendi muito bem como funciona o counter para este exemplo.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: O problema não ficou muito claro, principalmente porque não é definido a regra que o código tenta aplicar na formação do resultado.

Comment: Opa, amigo, tudo bem? Peço desculpa pelo código, sou usuario iniciante.

Comment: Mas o objetivo basicamente é printar apenas as linhas que contem proxy_pass e server_name, uma abaixo da outra, pois são informações únicas pra mim, seja printando em um xls ou txt.

Comment: O primeiro bloco que adicionou, todas aquelas \ fazem parte do texto, ou ficou desconfigurado somente aqui para nós?

Comment: São daquela forma mesmo, documento totalmente fora de padrão, onde preciso pegar as infos server_name e proxy_pass e printar em um txt ou xls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizei o teste aqui e está trazendo todos os dados do arquivo. Porém, a forma que quer tratar estes dados eu não apliquei, pois não sei de fato como deseja.
Caso não esteja da forma que desejar me comunique que edito ou removo a resposta:

```
with open("APIsfrontResult", "w") as api_result_write:
    with open("APIsfront.txt", "r") as api_result:
        for line in api_result:
            line = line[:-1]
            list_search = ["server_name", "proxy_pass"]
            for val_search in list_search:
                if val_search in line:
                    api_result_write.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: Wellington, muito obrigado pela ajuda, para primeiro passo que eu desejava com seu exemplo consegui solucionar o meu problema inicial!! Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Sobre o tratamento de dados, eu estou estudando uma forma de printar somente as linhas do proxy_pass e a linha anterior, que no caso seria a server_name a partir de uma lista de palavras chave. Você poderia me indicar algo, por gentileza? Novamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Mas com relação ao problema que tinha sobre o server_name e ao proxy_pass a minha resposta está correta? Se sim, creio que deve marcar como respondida. Pois a tratativa já entra como outro pergunta. Não?

Comment: Esta corretissima amigo!! Marquei, desculpe, minha primeira vez na plataforma. Seria melhor criar uma nova pergunta para a parte 2, o que vc sugere?

Comment: Creio que uma segunda pergunta seria melhor, desta forma ficará disponível para todos da plataforma analisar e responder. Só tome cuidado para que sua pergunta não seja uma faça pra mim. Ou seja, tente encontrar um modelo que quer seguir, monte-o e caso realmente não consiga, questione no stack junto ao código para que possam lhe auxiliar. Entendeu?

Comment: Excelente, amigo. É na mesma linhagem, apenas filtrando o regex, ainda estou em busca de um modelo do tema e tentando fazer. Valeu por toda ajuda!! Grande abraço, amigo!!

Comment: Wellington, pode me tirar uma ultima duvida? Como e o funcionamento da linha line = line[:-1], estou estudando a alguns dias os contadores, mas ainda esta um pouco dificil o entendimento, rsrs

Comment: [teste online](https://ideone.com/MhMlbz), para que entenda melhor fiz um pequeno exemplo, [documentação python](https://aprendendo-computacao-com-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/capitulo_07.html#fatias-de-strings)